# python OOP unexpected results

Tags: python, oop

I have a list containing lists of objects. More specifically,

```
l = [ [X1,X2],[X3,X4]]
```

where `X1,X2,X3,X4` are objects.

Now, I have a method in the class definition, that takes a list of objects, and modifies the attribute of the present object. Thus,

```
    Class X:
          def __init__(self,value=1):
             self.value = value
          def func (self,l):
             total = 0
             for x in l:
               total += x.value
          self.value = total
```

The problem I encounter is as follows. I have to apply the function func on elements of l[1] using elements of l[0]. However, when I do so, it turns out that the elements of l[0] are also getting changed. Thus, when I input

```
for obj in l[1]:
   obj.func(l[0])
```

then I see that elements of l[0] have values that should ideally be assigned to l[1]. 
the list lis created as follows.

```
l0 = []
for i in range(2):
  newx= X(i)
l.append(newx)
l=[]
l.append(l0)
l.append(l0)
```

What am I missing?

Correction: It seems python doesn't create new list objects every time I append an existing list.I basically need to copy the list using copy command. Hence, it is modifying the existing object.

Comment: This is a very confusing question

Comment: I omitted the class definition for convenience.Assume that class X has only one attribute called value.

Comment: How was `l` and `X1..X4` created? Are the `id()` the same for the objects

Comment: _"I omitted the class definition for convenience"_. I appreciate the thought, but when composing a [mcve] it's more important to be complete than minimal. If readers can't run the code on their machines, you removed too much.

Comment: _"the list is created as follows"_. You're appending `newx` to a list outside of the loop, so only the final value gets added. And you're appending it to `l`, which doesn't exist yet. Something's not right here.

Comment: Convenience means we can copy your code and run it in our Python. Anything else is not convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l.append(l0)
l.append(l0)
```

Here you are appending the same list twice. Changes to objects in one list will be seen in the other because they are the same list.

To get the result you want, you must create two lists rather than reuse the first list.

Comment: got it...I basically need to copy a list in order to create a new separate copy of it....presently I am not creating new objects...

Comment: @python_tensorflow be very careful. If you just copy the list, you will then have two different lists, but the objects in the lists will be identical, so you will still see the same results. You also need to create new objects for the second list.